# dynamically setting year, while showing sum by month

Tags: sql-server

so i want to query the table where it shows the sum of cost by month and the year should be dynamic, i wrote this query but it doesnt sum the cost.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT TOP 100 2003 + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY PostingDate) AS Yr, SUM(Amount) as Total
  FROM table1
  GROUP BY PostingDate
  ) Years
WHERE Yr <= YEAR(GETDATE())
```

it should be

```
month  cost     year 
jan    12.00    2011
feb    10.00    2011
```

then another column for year 2010. Is this possible

..

Comment: What does the table/data look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
 CASE
    WHEN DATEPART(month, PostingDate) = 1 then 'Jan',
    WHEN DATEPART(month, PostingDate) = 2 then 'Feb',
    WHEN DATEPART(month, PostingDate) = 3 then 'March',
    WHEN DATEPART(month, PostingDate) = 4 then 'April',
    WHEN DATEPART(month, PostingDate) = 5 then 'May',
    WHEN DATEPART(month, PostingDate) = 6 then 'Jun',
    WHEN DATEPART(month, PostingDate) = 7 then 'Jul',
    WHEN DATEPART(month, PostingDate) = 8 then 'Aug',
    WHEN DATEPART(month, PostingDate) = 9 then 'Sep',
    WHEN DATEPART(month, PostingDate) = 10 then 'Oct',
    WHEN DATEPART(month, PostingDate) = 11 then 'Nov',
 ELSE 'DEC' as [Month],
 SUM(Amount) as Total,
 DATEPART(year, PostingDate) as [Year]
FROM
  Table1
WHERE
  DATEPART(year, PostingDate) <= DATEPART(year, GETDATE())
GROUP BY
  DATEPART(year, PostingDate) as [Year],
  DATEPART(month, PostingDate) as [Month]
```

Note: untested just done in notepad :/